# why hive doesn't show empty partition count when i use group by?

Tags: mapreduce, group-by, hive, hdfs

this is just a curiosity: why hive doesn't show empty partition count when i use group by?

```
select count(*), partition_date 
from table 
group by partition_date;
```

result is:

```
count----------------partition_date
746 ----------------20160901
1155----------------20160906
589 ----------------20160907
639 ----------------20160908
763 ----------------20160909
1502----------------20160912
1188----------------20160913
601 ----------------20160914
675 ----------------20160915
766 ----------------20160916
```

Now i wasn't able to see 3 partitions: 20160905, 20160904, 20160903.

If i do a count on these specific partitions it gives me count=0.

```
select count(*) from table where partition_date=20160905;
select count(*) from table where partition_date=20160904;
select count(*) from table where partition_date=20160903;
```

But this way i did it without using group by, and that's why it gives me a result.

If i do it again using group by, i still get a void result

```
select count(*), partition_date from table where partition_date=20160905 group by partition_date;
```

I tried in other ways, but i still can't get the count of empty partitions using group by...

```
select count(*), partition_date from table group by partition_date having count(*)>=0;
select count(*), partition_date from table group by partition_date having count(*)=0;
select count(*), partition_date from table where partition_date in (20160905, 20160904, 20160903) group by partition_date;
```

This is the only solution that i found, there is another way?

```
select AA.partition_date,nvl(BB.CN,0) as CC 
from (select distinct partition_date as partition_date from table) AA 
left join 
    (select partition_date, count(*) as CN from table group by partition_date) BB 
on AA.partition_date = BB.partition_date;
```

So my final questions are:

- is this related to MapReduce Jobs?
- How these MapReduce jobs works to give results of these queries?
- Do you know a tricky way to count empty partitions?